# How to unpack user payload with gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm new to golang and coming from Python. I was wondering if there's a way to unpack data after validating it. Specifically, I want to convert here from a struct to a Gorm Model.

In python I'm used to doing something like this:

```
user_payload = {'id': 123, 'name': 'alex', 'preferences': ['one', 'two']}
new_user = UserORM(**user_payload)
session.commit(new_user)
```

Where the `**user_payload` bit is equivalent to me writing this:

```
new_user = UserORM(id=123, name='alex', preferences=['one', 'two'])
```

This is the golang project I'm mucking around with and trying to figure out how to implement this in:

```
// Media controller

func CategorizeMedia(context *gin.Context) {
    payload, err := ValidateRequest[CategorizeMediaRequest](context)
    if err != nil {
        context.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }
    media := models.Media{Category: &payload.Category,
        Date:        payload.DescriptiveFields.Date,
        Description: payload.DescriptiveFields.Description,
        People:      payload.DescriptiveFields.People,
        Tags:        payload.DescriptiveFields.Tags,
    }

    if err := database.Connection.Create(&media).Error; err != nil {
        context.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }
    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"done": true})
}
```

```
// Request models

package controllers

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "time"
)

type DescriptiveFields struct {
    Date        *time.Time `json:"date"`
    Description *string    `json:"description"`
    People      *[]string  `json:"people"`
    Tags        *[]string  `json:"tags"`
}

type CategorizeMediaRequest struct {
    Category          string            `json:"category" binding:"required"`
    DescriptiveFields DescriptiveFields `json:"descriptors"`
}

// Removed the other models mentioned here for simplicity's sake

func ValidateRequest[T CreateUserRequest | DeleteUserRequest | LoginRequest | CategorizeMediaRequest |
    EditMediaRequest | UpdateUserRequest](context *gin.Context) (T, error) {
    var payload T
    err := context.ShouldBindJSON(&payload)
    return payload, err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to set all the arguments explicitly and there is no built-in analogue to Python's kwargs in Go.
You can write the method, say `mediaPayloadToModel` and re-use it if it's necessary